# Displaying the time in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE to build a C++ Project, Is there an option to display the time the build has ended from the IDE console.

Or an option to dispaly the time taken for the build.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a post-build step, thus:

1. Select Project Properties | C/C++ Build | Settings, then Build Steps tab.
2. In the Post-Build Steps edit-box, enter a command such as 'cmd.exe /c "date/t & time/t" ' for Windows or just 'date' for Linux (minus the single quotes).
3. Do the build, and you'll see the date/time shown in the Build console output.

With a combination of pre- and post-build steps, and batch files (Windows) or shell scripts (Linux), you could find a way to print the total build time. Just save the date/time in the pre-build step, then compare it to the date/time in the post-build step, thus deriving an elapsed time.